# 'mdls' does not display all metadata for hidden files

Tags: macos, command-line, spotlight, metadata

The short man page of 'mdls' gives every indication that it should list all metadata by default. For some reason, I'm only getting a small portion:

```
vima@artemis[~]: mdls .bash_history
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate = 2018-02-04 18:56:51 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate      = 2018-01-04 17:41:32 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode       = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags       = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon     = 0
kMDItemFSInvisible         = 1
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery      = 0
kMDItemFSLabel             = 0
kMDItemFSName              = ".bash_history"
kMDItemFSNodeCount         = 7376
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID      = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID       = 502
kMDItemFSSize              = 7376
kMDItemFSTypeCode          = ""
```

The missing metadata is still there, because I can call for it:

```
vima@artemis[~]: mdls -name kMDItemContentType .bash_history

kMDItemContentType = "public.data"
```

Any ideas why I'm not getting everything at once?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running? The output seems a bit odd, because my mdls does not output a newline at the start of the output - are you sure you haven't done something so that the first part of the output is hidden/removed by your terminal software or similar? - mdls shows the ItemContentType by default without problems.

Comment: 10.13.3. Ignore the newline. I just ran it again, and mdls didn't output the newline, I must have done that accidentally when I pasted the output. Sorry about that.

Comment: Did anyone ever solve this? I am having exactly the same problem with only the same "kMDItemFS..." values being returned, even though there are actually other metadata in the file. macOS Mojave, 10.14.6 In my case I can't get the metadata using the -name flag on my machine. However, if I zip up the file and send it to another user they are able to see a lot more metadata from that file which I know to be there because it is showing up in another app on my machine.

Comment: I never did figure this out. I'm still using 10.14.6 also, it might be a version specific bug. Curious if this problem exists on Catalina, but at this point I'm skipping that whole release and waiting for WWDC.